# Connection to Network, Servers

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8

I want to know if I can set up a server not connected to the internet, so as to not loose the connection to my files when the net goes down. I'm not sure if I have phrased the question right but that's what on my mind.

Also, is it possible to connect to a server on long distance. Say about 1k KM.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What server do you want to run? Standard windows file sharing, HTTP, FTP...and so on?

Comment: Of course you can set up network services without the Internet. I sense the actual question would be how to create a long-range “local” network.

Answer (score 0):

If the file server is inside your LAN , then there is no need for internet connection.

**Also, is it possible to connect to a server on long distance. Say about 1k KM.**

It depends on network cable type you are using:

- If you are using UTP CAT6 or earlier , it can only go for 100M, so you will need switches per 100M to applify the signal .
- You could use [Multi-mode optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber) cables, but you will switches that support Fiber , or has [SFPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver).

OR, if you are 1KM away from the server, you could get a second internet connection in the new site/location (which is 1KM away from server) , and publish the file server, so you could access it over internet.